# Error while drawing shape on Canvas Windows 10 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-8.1-universal

I am creating an app that draws shapes on canvas and those shapes are recognized as letters using https://github.com/phatware/WritePadSDK sdk for writing pad. but the problem is that this api code works fine when it is used in windows 8.1 project but when the same code is used in windows 10 universal app it produces error when i debugged the code. Code of xaml is given bellow

```
     <Canvas   Background="WhiteSmoke" Name="InkCanvas" PointerPressed="OnCanvasPointerPressed"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" PointerReleased="OnCanvasPointerReleased" PointerCaptureLost="OnCanvasPointerCaptureLost" PointerExited="InkCanvas_OnPointerExited" PointerMoved="OnCanvasPointerMoved" LostFocus="InkCanvas_LostFocus">
```

and the code which is recognizes the shape using sdk is given bellow which is executed on PointerReleased event of Canvas:-

```
 var resultValue = recognizerShared.RecognizeStrokes(InkCanvas.Children.ToList(), false);
```

and when i inspected the method given in sdk i.e. **RecognizeStrokes** which does the recolonization i got error when  i did debugging

[image]

As this code works fine in windows 8.1 project i think it can be something todo with windows 10 universal app problem

**Excelption details is given bellow:-**

```
AccessKey = 'new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement>(strokes).Items[0].AccessKey' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
```

AccessKeyScopeOwner = 'new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(strokes).Items[0].AccessKeyScopeOwner' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

AllowFocusOnInteraction = '((Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement)new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(strokes).Items[0]).AllowFocusOnInteraction' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

AllowFocusWhenDisabled = '((Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement)new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(strokes).Items[0]).AllowFocusWhenDisabled' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

ContextFlyout = 'new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(strokes).Items[0].ContextFlyout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

ExitDisplayModeOnAccessKeyInvoked = 'new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(strokes).Items[0].ExitDisplayModeOnAccessKeyInvoked' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

FocusVisualMargin = '((Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement)new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(strokes).Items[0]).FocusVisualMargin' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

FocusVisualPrimaryBrush = '((Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement)new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(strokes).Items[0]).FocusVisualPrimaryBrush' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(strokes).Items[0].IsAccessKeyScope

Please help me to solve the problem above.

Link to download the sample project code is given bellow for testing where you can see the problem

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xbtxbxwyoyuf00/WindowsSDK.rar?dl=0

Thanks!

Comment: Have recompiled the library (from Win 8.1) to target UWP/Win10? Also note that Win10 now has great built-in ink analysis/recognition APIs, so you need to use an external library for that anymore: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.analysis